# Python Kivy - Issue moving canvas objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

After running different aspects on trying to update an item within the canvas. The objects refuse to move within the canvas, even if I have the reference to the object itself I cannot set its position. The portion of the code I am providing here seems to be the only real issue. It runs through the Screen getting a widget and the widget contains a canvas along with labels. I am able to go through the labels without issue and same with the canvas objects. Only difference being that I cannot reposition the canvas objects but I have zero issue with the labels.

Is there a special attribute or method to update or change the canvas objects positions?
I have tried using ask_update(), draw(), flagging the object moved and etc. I am not sure as to why it does not work.

```
         if type(obj).__name__ == DonateButton.__name__:
            cnv_items = [child for child in obj.canvas.children]
            for cnv_obj in cnv_items:
                if type(cnv_obj).__name__ in [Ellipse.__name__, RoundedRectangle.__name__]:
                    cnv_obj.pos = (0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group` instructions of `canvas` to change the attributes of its objects on the fly. Below is an example showing `Rectangle` and `Ellipse` objects under one `canvas` with changing `pos` attribute with randomly generated numbers:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
import random

APP_KV = """
<CanvasTest>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            group: 'rectangle'
            size: 400, 200
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Ellipse:
            group: 'ellipse'
            size: 200, 100
            pos: self.pos
"""

class CanvasTest(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.test_pos, 1)
        
    def test_pos(self, *args):
        self.canvas.get_group('rectangle')[0].pos = random.randrange(1, Window.width - 400), random.randrange(1, Window.height - 200)
        self.canvas.get_group('ellipse')[0].pos = random.randrange(1, Window.width - 200), random.randrange(1, Window.height - 100)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(APP_KV)
        return CanvasTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```